# A little confusion about complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega$ a open subset of $\mathbb{C}.$ If $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$ is $\mathcal{C}^{1},$ then $f$ is analytic?

I know that $f$ is analytic, then $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^{1}.$ But, by Cauchy's Integral Formula, the conversely is true?

Comment: The converse is indeed true, i.e. every holomorphic function is analytic. This is a cornerstone of complex analysis, see https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Holomorphic_Function_is_Analytic

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Thank you so much, sir!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Using Cauchy's integral formula, it is immediate to see that an Holomorphic function is $C^{\infty}$. With the help if the dominated convergence theorem, we can also see that it is analytic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean with the situation.

If $f(x+iy)$ is just $\mathcal{C}^{1}$ with respect to $x,y\in\mathbb{R},$ then $f$ need not be analytic.

But if $f(z)$ is $\mathcal{C}^{1}$ with respect to $z\in\mathbb{C},$ i.e. if $f$ satisfies the [Cauchy-Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations), then $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ and analytic.